# Erosion Operation without using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to programming and I am now working on a python program for erosion operation. Since it is an assignment, it is not allowed to use the functions in OpenCV. I have tried my program for an array with a small kernel (size: 2x2). The program works and gives a correct result. However, when a larger kernel (size: 5x5) is used, the program gives no result that the 'if' loop is not being run. Can someone help?

Program 1 (with small kernel):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
    
 image_array = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,0,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1]])
    
 kernel_array = np.array([[1,1],
                          [1,1]])
    
 erosion = np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.uint32)
    
 for i in range(5-1):
    for j in range(5-1):
        if (image_array[i][j] == 1 and
            image_array[i][j+1] == 1 and
            image_array[i+1][j] == 1 and
            image_array[i+1][j+1] == 1):
                            
                erosion[i][j] = 255
                print(erosion)
```

Program 2 (with larger kernel):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

image_np_array = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])

kernel_array = np.array([[0,1,1,1,0],
                         [1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1]
                         [1,1,1,1,1]
                         [0,1,1,1,0]])

erosion_np_array = np.zeros((13,13),dtype=np.uint32)

for i in range(13-4):
    for j in range(13-4):
        while (image_np_array[i][j] == 0 and
               image_np_array[i][j+1] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i][j+2] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i][j+3] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i][j+4] == 0 and
               image_np_array[i+1][j] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+1][j+1] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+1][j+2] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+1][j+3] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+1][j+4] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+2][j] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+2][j+1] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+2][j+2] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+2][j+3] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+2][j+4] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+3][j] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+3][j+1] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+3][j+2] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+3][j+3] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+3][j+4] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+4][j] == 0 and
               image_np_array[i+4][j+1] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+4][j+2] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+4][j+3] == 1 and
               image_np_array[i+4][j+4] == 0):
                  
                  erosion_np_array[i+2][j+2] = 255
                  print(erosion_np_array)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `while` in Program 2 should be an `if` like Program 1?

Comment: Yes, I use 'if' first in my 2nd program, but no result is provided (noting printed). So I tried using 'while', but it is not working also.